# Problems with compass application

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to create a application for android that simulates a compass but as soon as I try to load it, the application crashes. I don't really know what to do anymore so any suggestion would be great.

The compass class looks like this:

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 19-09-2015.
 */
public class Compass extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {




    private ImageView compassImage;
    private SensorManager sensormanager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private Sensor magnometer;
    private float   currentCompassAngle = 0;
    private float[] readingmagnometer     = new float [3];
    private float[] readingaccelerometer  = new float [3];

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.compass);

        compassImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compass);
        sensormanager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensormanager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnometer = sensormanager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    }



    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
        float [] rotation    = new float[9];
        float [] orientation = new float[3];

        if(event.sensor == accelerometer)
        {
            readingaccelerometer[0] = event.values[0];
            readingaccelerometer[1] = event.values[1];
            readingaccelerometer[2] = event.values[2];
        }
        if(event.sensor == magnometer)
        {
            readingmagnometer[0] = event.values[0];
            readingmagnometer[1] = event.values[1];
            readingmagnometer[2] = event.values[2];
        }

        sensormanager.getRotationMatrix(rotation, null, readingaccelerometer, readingmagnometer);
        sensormanager.getOrientation(rotation, orientation);
        float azimuthRadians = orientation[0];
        float azimuthDegrees = -(float) (Math.toDegrees(azimuthRadians)+360)%360;

        doAnimation(currentCompassAngle, azimuthDegrees, compassImage);
        currentCompassAngle = azimuthDegrees;
    }


    private void doAnimation(float from, float to, View rotateme)
    {
        RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
                from,
                to,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        ra.setDuration(200);
        ra.setFillAfter(true);
        rotateme.startAnimation(ra);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        sensormanager.unregisterListener(this, accelerometer);
        sensormanager.unregisterListener(this,magnometer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();


        sensormanager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        sensormanager.registerListener(this, magnometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    }
}
```

Basically it's just an image of a compass (it opens in another window) that can be accesses trough the main activity.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView compass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Rust.otf");
        TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        TextView myTextView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
        myTextView2.setTypeface(myTypeFace);

        compass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compass_button);
        compass.setOnClickListener(clickoncompass);

    }

    View.OnClickListener clickoncompass = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Compass.class);
            startActivity(i);

}
};

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat? So we can check the error.

Comment: In my compass code I test for both rotation and accelerometer values not being null before calling sensorManager.getRotationMatrix.(..).